# How can I show a read-only version of Google Calendar on Apple TV 4th generation?

Tags: calendar, appletv, google-calendar

I've a mentally retarded brother that I gave an Apple TV 4th generation.

He loves it because of the YouTube player on it.

I'd like to display a read-only version of a Google Calendar on it to see if we can replace his paper calendar.

That way his care-takers can better cooperate in maintaining the read-write version of his calendar so he sees the read-only version of it (now often his paper one gets out of sync).

I tried searching for apps, but haven't found a suitable one yet.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you explain how you would like this to work? How can his care-takers better cooperate in maintaining his calendar if it's read only?

Comment: @Little.Eden I hope my edit explains that well enough.

Comment: I think you have to approach this from the perspective that it's not your brother's calendar but rather the care takers' calendar they are sharing with your brother.

Comment: @Allan my basic idea was to have a read-write calendar account that has all the events in it and an Apple TV specific account that has read-only permissions for the calendar. Now I need to find an app that allows displaying this calendar. I found one for iPad, but not one for Apple TV: https://www.macrumors.com/2017/03/29/google-calendar-ipad-app/

Comment: I did a quick [Bing search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=calendar+app+apple+tv&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) for "calendar app appletv" and found this [Calendar App for AppleTV App](http://calendarforappletv.com/).  It's about half way down the page.  Will that App work?

Comment: Thanks for that! I will give it a try and let the answer know.